# What's the common name for this unwanted effect?

Tags: video, video-streaming, video-processing, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

Consider the following video:

https://anonfile.com/7d9bkfe1bc/upload.mp4

That effect is unwanted. It's like a mixed-past-and-current frames situation, making a kinda "shaky" effect. But "shakiness" is something else entirely in the video editing jargon.

I'm trying to find out its causes. But it's getting troublesome to try to explain the problem itself to my peers, and/or even trying to search for common causes.

So, my question is: **What could be a common name for this effect?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to call it jitter, judder or stutter. As far as i see your problem is not a common one, so you might have a hard time finding the cause in the net.

A similar common mistake would be: reversed-field judder

But in that case, the frames would be mixed up only every 20ms. in your video it looks more like frames are mixed up every 250ms or so. Maybe you deal with multiple troubles, like  reversed-field judder plus deinterlacing plus frame rate conversion.

Anyway, as your source material is soccer, i guess the original source is interlaced so there is a chance that you really deal with some kind of de-interlacing issue.